# France "Passport Talent" visa - validity

Tags: visas, france

I applied for a "Passport Talent" visa for France. I got the visa today but am confused about the meaning of the dates written on it. The information written on the visa is:

- Valid for: France
- From: 11-12-22
- Until: 10-04-23
- Duration of stay: XXX
- Type of visa: D
- Number of entries: Mult
- Remarks: Pass. Talent; Chercheur; PT4 VLSTS; Valider en ligne

1. Confusion 1: It says "valid for France". Does it mean I can't enter other EU countries?
2. Confusion 2: It is valid for 4 months from 11-Dec-22 to 10-Apr-23. Does it mean that I have to leave France before 10-Apr-23 regardless of when I enter? Or does it mean that I can stay for 4 months even if I enter France on 09-Apr-23?

Comment: AFAIK you will need to visit your local police station within 3 months of your arrival in France to request a multi-year residence permit corresponding to your situation. The visa allows you time to do that. But as this question is about long term stays you should ask on https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Traveller This is not the case, they won't get a card and their visa is valid for the whole time, but they still need to validate their visa online, see my answer

Comment: I'd argue it's valid on both expats.SE and travel.SE. This question is about travelling within Schengen with a work visa for a specific country and has significant value on Travel.SE

Answer (score 5):

The situation with D visas is that you have different rights in the country which issued it and the rest of the Schengen countries.

In the country which issued it (the one in the “valid for” field, France in your case), you can:

- Stay as long as you want within the validity period of the visa (no 90/180 limitation)
- Work (within the rules of the specific visa)

You can still visit the other Schengen countries, but then the usual rules of a C visa apply:

- 90 days max and 90/180 rule (counting only the days in Schengen outside of France)
- You can’t work

So you can transit through another country (or several) on your way to/from France, you can visit friends and family or take a holiday for a short period of time in other Schengen countries, but you can’t use that visa to live and work in a different country, only France.

And yes, you must leave before the end of validity of the visa. However, that visa is only a "temporary" visa, if you are supposed to stay one year or more they only grant this short visa, and once you're in France you are supposed to ask for "carte de séjour" (residency permit) which will last longer and allow you to stay longer.

Comment: Thank you. Even if I validate my visa online after entering France, do I still have to leave before 4 April? I wanted to stay in France from 1 Feb to 30 Apr (3 months).

Comment: Apparently you have to convert your visa into a longer term “carte des séjour” once you are in France, see the procedure on the page shared by Nicolas

Answer (score 3):

You have recieved a Long stay visa valid as residence permit *Visa de long séjour valant Titre de séjour* or [VLS-TS](https://www.campusfrance.org/en/student-long-stay-visa).

This is specific to France, where the actual visa on your passport is legally equivalent to a residence permit that would be on a separate card in other countries.

But, as it is a residence permit *de facto*, you can enter any Schengen country to transit or, even have a short visit to other Schengen states, provided you stay in the 90/180 clock (the clock **doesn't** run while you're in France, only in other states)

Campus-France (the official agency that deals with foreign students) [states](https://www.campusfrance.org/en/student-long-stay-visa) :

> - travel freely in all the countries of the Schengen Area;
> - work 964 hours per year, i.e. 20 hours per week, to supplement their financial resources;
> - use the VISALE, the free security deposit service for students,
> - receive a rental subsidy from the CAF, the family allowance fund (caisse d'allocations familiales),
>   extend their stay beyond the period of validity of the issued residence permit.

---

**Note, you **MUST** [validate](https://www.campusfrance.org/en/how-to-validate-your-long-stay-visa-visa-long-sejour-upon-your-arrival-in-france) your visa online once in France**

If you don't :

> Holders of a multiple-entry VLS-TS student visa (VLS-TS "étudiant" à entrées multiples) are entitled to travel outside of France and in the entire world whenever they wish. Please be aware, however, that you must have validated your visa to travel outside of France  beyond the three months following your arrival in France.

> - During the first three months after your arrival in France, you are authorised to travel freely outside of France and in the entire world with your visa, even if you have not validated it.
> - After these three months, however, if you have not validated your visa and you travel outside of France, you will be required to apply for a new visa to return to France.

Comment: Thank you so much for the detailed reply. Currently, I am not planning to stay in France for more than 3 months. I will be working on a project with a professor at a French University. I want to start my stay in France from 1st Feb (till 30 Apr), but my visa says "valid until 4 Apr", will it be a problem? Even if I validate my visa online after entering France, I still have to leave before 4 April?

Comment: You have to leave while your visa/residence permit is still valid, if your visa states 4 April, then you must have left on or before that date, if this is a clerical error (i.e. you've asked for other dates, and they haven't given you those dates) you may want to contct the embassy else, you need to reapply for a new visa with the right dates

Comment: Oh god, I was under the impression that a Passport Talent visa is valid for 1 year.

Comment: It depends on what you applied, see [service public](https://www.service-public.fr/particuliers/vosdroits/F16922?lang=en)